# How can we convert List<SelectOption> to a List<string> in apex?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have a list of "selectoption" and I want to use this in my SOQL.

The WHERE IN clause gives me incompatible error.

Can we convert list of selectoption to a list of strings?

Answer (score 2):

What exactly you want to take from SelectOption items to list of strings - labels, values or something else? In any case, you can use getter-methods, like getLabel() or getValue() and collect them to list. For instance,

```
List<SelectOption> selectOptions = new List<SelectOption>(); //here it's empty, but you has filled one
List<String> stringValues = new List<String>();
for(SelectOption so: selectOptions){
    stringValues.add(so.getValue());
}

//use list of strings as you wish
```

You can find documentation about SelectOption methods [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_SelectOption_methods.htm).

Comment: Thanks Khajiit, It heped.